# Is L = { words such that the maximum number of as following a b is equal to the maximum number of bs following an a} context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Consider the language $L = \{w \in \Sigma^* \mid $ the maximum number of a's following a b is equal to the maximum number of b's following an a$\}$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$. So for example abbaab is in L, as there are at most 2 consecutive b's after an a and at most 2 consecutive a's after a b. Yet abbaba is not.

We can show using the pumping lemma for regular languages that L is not regular. Yet my colleague and I have failed to use the pumping lemma for context-free languages to show that L is not context-free, yet at the same time creating a PDA/CFG for this also seems impossible as it would need to remember the maximum it has encountered somewhere somehow. Just the stack of a PDA does not seem sufficient for this purpose.

So is $L$ context free?

Answer (score 0):

To use the pumping lemma for context-free languages to show that L is not context-free, we need to do the following:

We assume that L is context-free, p is the pumping length of L.
Choose a string w in L that has length at least p. $w = ab^p a^p b$ suffices.
Then showing that dividing w in every possible way into five parts u, v, x, y and z such that $|vxy| ≤ p$ and $|vy| ≥ 1$, the string $uv^k xy^k z$ is not in L for some $k ≥ 0$.

We divide w as follows:

$u = ab^{p-1}$

$v = b$

$x = a^{p-1}$

$y = \epsilon$

$z = ab$

The properties are still valid:

1. $|vxy| = |ba^{p-1}| = p$, which is less or equal than p.
2. |vy| ≥ 1, because vy = b.
3. $w \in L$

Then $uv^2 xy^2 z = ab^{p+1} a^{p} b$, which is not in L because the maximum number of a’s following a b is $p$, but the maximum number of b’s following an a is $p+1$. We observe that this division contradicts the pumping property, and L is not context free.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work right? We need a contradiction in all possible splits...? Consider u = ab^p-1, v = b, x = epsilon, y = a, z = a^p-1 b. Now we can pump to our hearts content, no?

Comment: True, wouldn't it only be possible to solve with a "super" PDA that has an infinite stack alphabet, such that it is possible to memorize of the maximum amount of consecutive symbols, e.g. using integers as the stack alphabet and incrementing them, essentially a TM?

Comment: While it is indeed decidable (though an infinite alphabet is not required for that once we have a TM), that does not really help us in proving this thing is not context-free.